# Fastest way to search a SQL Server table (or indexed view) column with "like '%search%'"?

Tags: search, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

Suppose there's a table with columns (`UserID`, `FieldID`, `Value`), with half a million records. I want to see if some search term T(N) occurs anywhere in each `Value` (i.e. `Value.Contains( T(N) )` ).

I think I'm just hitting a wall volume wise, just too many values to sift through. I don't think a Full Text index will help, because it's only useful for `StartsWith` queries that look at individual words, not occurrences anywhere within the string at all.

Is there a good approach to indexing this kind of data for such a search in SQL Server?

Comment: What kind of "value"? Just some words, long text?

Answer (score 0):

A half-million records is not terribly large, although I don't know the size of the field contents. A couple of ideas - this was too long for a comment or else I may have posted as such.

You could implement a full-text search engine like Elastic, Solr, etc and use it as a sidecar. If when you are doing text searches, you are not otherwise making much use of the other data, this might be easy enough. Note that you could put other data for searching into Elastic or Solr, but I'm not sure if you'd want to duplicate all your data, and those tools aren't really great for a transactional data store.

Another option for volumes this small, assuming you only need basic "contains" searching: create two more tables: keywords and keyword_index (or whatever). When saving, tokenize your text content and write out any new keywords to keywords table and then add the data to the join table. Index everything, and then do your search off the keywords table, joining back to the master via the intermediate keyword_index table.

This is fairly hackish, and getting your keyword handling really dialed in (for stemming, etc) may be a pain. It is a reasonable quick & dirty solution for smaller-scale needs though.

Comment: The values average 7 characters with a min length of 1 and a max length of 88.  I decided to implement a 2-level-deep inverse index of character pairs, which will point to matching records (it will actually support N-levels deep). There are 1,311,126 pairs of characters (padding with a space at the end of each value), but only 1,242 *unique* pairs.  Sqrt(1242) ~ 36, so there are about 36 unique characters on average.  I managed to implement such an index with just a single class and about 50 lines of code that allows searches to complete blazingly fast now. Yay.

Comment: @Triynko - sounds like a good approach and the character pair index, if I am imagining the implementation correctly (or roughly so) should obviate some of the issues from the brute-force large index approach I mentioned as a second option.